# How to call httpget instead of post for pageload in MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a create form in ASP.Net MVC5. When the page loads there is some data to be fetched from DB and on button submit click, the create controller should be called to save the data. The problem is when the page loads it always goes to HTTP POST method instead of the get method.(I know few such questions are already raised but nothing helps me here) If I rename HTTP POST method name, then it calls get method correctly. Having two actions with same name, it always calls HTTP POST method while page loads and button click doesn't call any action method.

This is Sharepoint high trust provider app for ASP.Net MVC hence my URL will be different while browsing.

My view and controllers looks like this. Is there anything wrong here?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Test"))    
{    

    <div class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
                    </div>
                </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>       
    </div>
 }

public ActionResult Create()    
{   
    MyModel model = new MyModel();
    string usersid = ((System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity)(HttpContext.User.Identity)).User.Value;

            //Bind Board details
            eDataAccess mda = new eDataAccess();
            ExtDataTable committees = mda.GetList(usersid, "--url--");

            GetAllUserList(model.comitteeslist.FirstOrDefault().Value, usersid);

            // few logic

           return View(model);
}

    [HttpPost]     
    public ActionResult Create(MyModel model)    
    {
string usersid = ((System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity)(HttpContext.User.Identity)).User.Value;
   // few logic
                int id = Utilities.Create(model.Title, usersid, 2057, 6297,
                   model.desc, false, model.start, model.end);

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Does this happen every time, on every page load, even the first time you load your page or does it happen only after you submitted the data for the first time? (Please take the `FormMethod.Get` out; my answer was wrong).

Comment: It is a small project and has only one view as of now.It happens every time for the page load

Comment: The first `ActionResult` method's signature doesn't take any parameter. So, it would be the one called when your page first loads up. The second one, takes a `Model` and would be the one called when you submit your form. Have you tried to add `[HttpGet]` attribute to the first one? I honestly don't get what you're trying to do here. Maybe you're not being clear on your explanation.

Comment: No that doesnt help. I have already tried it.My view has lot of other controls for which the data comes from DB. upon user's entry and submission the data will be created in DB. I just didnt paste entire view as its big

Comment: Actually, if you don't add `[HttpPost]`, it's automatically considered a GET.

Comment: So your first page load up comes with some `Model` data already? If so, you don't have any `ActionResult` defined in the `controller` to receive this call.

Comment: Yeah.thats correct. But I cant have submit button then. It never calls the controller correctly.May be I have to go for another way of doing button click

Comment: Try adding the `[HttpGet]` attribute to your first `ActionResult`, but change its signature to `public ActionResult Create(MyModel model)`. I'm assuming the data coming is the same `Model` that's being submitted in your form.

Comment: I'm surprised you're not getting an exception here: `return View(model);`, as you don't have any variable `model` declared anywhere, nor being received as a parameter in the method.

Comment: I cant change signature that way. compiler wont allow two methods overloaded with same signature. I have initialised model inside the controller.

Comment: I dont have any other issues other than this post method gets called for pageload if I have overloaded methods.Logic is fine.

Comment: @Ramee, please be clear on this: When you load the page, NOT by clicking the button, but just browsing to it when the URL ends with **.../Test/Create** - Which action is called?

Comment: @ilanS, when browsing the action gets called is second one with [Httppost] attribute. If this attribute is added to first method then first action is getting called. The point is it calls only the action with this attribtue

Comment: @Ramee, can you put your mode here? maybe it's not bounded correctly.

Comment: What you describe is strange... it contradicts the asp.net MVC behavior...

Comment: @ilanS, I have posted my code. There are big logics handled so I have posted a gist. Again there are no issues with my action methods as I have tested them throughly. It is only how to make them invoke for page load and button click.

Comment: This is very abnormal. Something must be mixed up somewhere. I'd suggest creating a new project and piece by piece rebuild the what you've got here with the most basic parts/code first.

Comment: @SethMW, It works fine in a new ASP.Net MVC5 project. I just copy pasted my view, controllers and model. So I guess it may be something to do with the provider app. I am researching in that aspect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending several hours I found a solution for my problem. I have changed my main page load action method just to redirect to another action method. This second action has the actual logic and both get and post methods. This way it works fine.

I still don't have answer why it behaves this way. However this solution helps and works fine.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return RedirectToAction("Create");
}

public ActionResult Create()    
{   
     MyModel model = new MyModel();
     string usersid = ((System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity)(HttpContext.User.Identity)).User.Value;

     //Bind Board details
     eDataAccess mda = new eDataAccess();
     ExtDataTable committees = mda.GetList(usersid, "--url--");
     GetAllUserList(model.comitteeslist.FirstOrDefault().Value, usersid);
    // few logic
     return View(model);
 }

[HttpPost]     
public ActionResult Create(MyModel model)    
{
  string usersid = ((System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity)(HttpContext.User.Identity)).User.Value;
 // few logic
 int id = Utilities.Create(model.Title, usersid, 2057, 6297,
               model.desc, false, model.start, model.end);
 return View();
}
```